# How to get generic type parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the code below, I want to get type of E.
But I can't find get type of E.

```
class A<E> {
  getParameterType() {
    // I want get type of E
  }
}

class B {
}

** Example **
new A<number>().getParameterType() // number
new A<B>().getParameterType() // B
```

Comment: This might be helpful in determining types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html

Comment: I don't think you can. Typescript only works at compile time, your function runs at runTime and thus has no way to access that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type safe approach to do this:

```js
class A<E> {
    constructor(public generic: E) { }
    getParameterType() {
        return this.generic
    }
}

class B {
}

const result1 = new A(42).getParameterType() // number
const result2 = new A(new B()).getParameterType() // B
```

Please be aware that it is unsafe  to use explicit generic which is not related to any argument:

```js
function fn<Char extends "a">(): Char {
    return "a" // error
}

const result = fn<'a' & { hello: 42 }>()

const check = result.hello // 42,but undefined in runtime
```

[Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments), in my article, you can find more about inference.